# How can I port forward on the Sagemcom F@st 5260 router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I have set up a MAMP server on my MacbookPro and I want to port forward it. When I log in to my router's home page and add a new port forwarding rule then reboot the router, nothing happens. I have successfully done this before with my old router. A few months ago we got it upgraded for free and our internet speed jumped from 20mbit/second to 100mb/second.

I have looked through nearly every Q&A/forum site, tutorial, and article trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. They all seem to be using different firmware in the screenshots so I contacted Spectrum, my ISP. Throughout an hour and a half, I went through 4 departments and 5 people. In the end, I was told to trade in my router for an older model with better documentation because they didn't know how to help me any further with my new router. They also told me that they were a level 3 technician and couldn't transfer me to a higher department because one didn't exist. I then contacted Sagemcom, the manufacturer of the router, and received the following email:

"Hello

I send you a screenshot of the port forwarding, you must use another internet access fort he test because the router doesn’t accept the Nat Loopback.

Best regard"

With [these](http://www.mediafire.com/file/oxo4iqxnw4ody40/Sagemcom_Response_Files.zip) files attached.

So you know what I am doing [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ena3op3kc3eryvg/How_I_tried_to_port_forward.zip) are screenshots showing the steps I took.

Edit:

I tried accessing my server on my phone using cellular with wifi turned off, only for it to still not connect.

Comment: I've not looked through your files, but the manufacturer's response seems to be quite clearly saying that you cannot test external port forwarding from within your router's intranet. You need to test from a friend's machine in another location, from work or from an internet café. If it's port 80 that you're forwarding, then you can test by using an HTTP proxy, or if it's an FTP port you can use [net2ftp](https://www.net2ftp.com/) to test. It is quite possible that you are setting up the forwarding rule correctly, but not testing correctly.

Comment: @Ramhound that misses the point entirely. Loopback of NAT translations allows you to test/access exposed services internally with feature parity to external access, without hacks involving /etc/hosts or DNS. If e.g. you are exposing 192.168.1.200:443 to host `https://example.com`, you can't access it using `https://192.168.1.200:443` because the certificate/SNI/host header don't match. Most consumer routers have been smart enough to implement loopback of NAT connections for years.  The designers of this router seem to have been oblivious to the need for this very common and convenient feature.